# Apache + Redis return a meaningful HTTP response

Tags: apache, redis

I'd like to keep number of comments on every post in Redis (to show these numbers next to post headlines at the home page).

That is: in Redis I'd like to organize simple mapping: post_id - number of comments.
In order maximize the speed of reaction, I'd like to avoid touching php.

The question: is it possible to organize http request with a post ID which Apache2 transmits to Redis, and Redis returns number of comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible only with a special module or other middleware that will convert your HTTP request to a Redis call and then convert back the response. Please have a look at this GitHub project https://github.com/sneakybeaky/mod_redis - it claims to do exactly what you are looking for.

Edit: since `mod_redis` project seems no longer active - you might want to have a look at [Webdis](http://webd.is/), which is a simple HTTP server itself that forwards requests to Redis.